# postgis insert query to store geometry and other data

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query

I'm using Postgis functions `st_dump` and `st_split` to split a polygon based on line. Now, after splitting; output geometry stores in a database table as well. Here is the query:

```
insert into aoo(geom)
SELECT ST_AsTEXT ((ST_Dump(ST_Split(circle, line))).geom) As wkt
FROM (SELECT 
    ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(73.33393335342407 33.82005181729661,73.33685159683228 33.80960466650892)',4326) As line,
    (select geom As circle from aoo where gid=71) ) As foo;
```

But, the issue is I want to store other data with these geometries as well. Like

```
insert into aoo(geom,name)
```

but I don't what is the way to do it.

Comment: What is the name of the field that you want to enter? is it also name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, others have tried well to answer my question. But those are not according to my requirements. What I did in this case is to handle the case at `Server-end.` Using PHP array, get the dumped geometries:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($rs)) 
        {
            $result[] = $row['wkt'];
        }
```

By using above snippet each `dumped` geometry is stored at an index in `$result` array. Hence, we can use `insert` or `update` query to store data other than geometries. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use ST_AsText when you want a geometry back -- it just will cast back to geometry  so a waste of cycles.

I'm not sure where your name field is coming from you want to insert, so I will assume it comes from your circle record. Note the trick is in your foo subselect you need to first list out all fields you want back.

```
INSERT INTO aoo(geom, name)
SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Split(circle, line))).geom, foo.name
  FROM ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(73.33393335342407 33.82005181729661,73.33685159683228 33.80960466650892)',4326) As line 
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT geom As circle, name from aoo where gid=71) As foo 
     ON ST_Intersects(line, foo.circle);
```

Comment: @LR1234567.. Actually, I want to enter the name field manually. It's not coming from somewhere. Entering it manually mean like any hard coded value we put into record.

Comment: In that case, why don't you just do: change my first  line to SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Split(circle, line))).geom, 'What I want here' As name

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
Insert INTO aoo(geom, out_name)
SELECT ST_AsTEXT ((ST_Dump(ST_Split(circle, line))).geom) As wkt, in_name
FROM (SELECT 
    ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(73.33393335342407 33.82005181729661,73.33685159683228 33.80960466650892)',4326) As line,
    (select geom As circle from aoo where gid=71) ) As foo;
```

where `out_name` is the fieldname of the name field in the destination table & `in_name` is the fieldname of the name field in the source table

Comment: I just have one table as you can see in the query: 
linestring geometry is added manually while 
polygon geometry is taken from table `aoo` and I want to store the output also in the same table.

Comment: Shouldn't you use an update query in that case?

Comment: I think I couldn't make my point clear.  `Splitted geometries` are being successfully storing in the table. Actually, I want to store data for other columns along with geometry simultaneously.